# Jquery set class to all elements except element with specific class + children/children of children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I want to hide all elements except for an element with a specific class AND all elements inside this.

right now im using

```
$("body").not(".embedded").hide();
```

But it also hides the elements inside my .embedded element.

I appreciate every help.

Comment: The problem is because you're hiding the `body`, so you're hiding *everything* inside the `body`. Can you give some more examples of your HTML structure and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Answer (score 2):

Use `*` and `space` to indicate all direct/nested children. Also, for the initial selector, use `body *` to indicate **all** children before the `not()` filtering

```
$("body *").not(".embedded, .embedded *").hide();
```

Comment: @AnoopJoshi, why not? space and * indicate all children

Comment: all elements are children of body. you are treating it as same level elements

Comment: No, with the `.embedded *` he selects everything INSIDE `.embedded`

Comment: Its works for me :) But i had to make 1 small change

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```js
$('body :not(".class2")').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="class1">11111</span>
<span class="class2">
    10
    <span class="class21">11</span>
    <span>12</span></span>
<span class="class1">11111</span>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. He doesn't want to hide the elements inside that class.

Comment: @Skatch: `But it also hides the elements inside my .embedded element.` is in the question.

Comment: Yeah, he doesn't want that to happen. Your code hides 11 and 12.